# Decoding unicode from Javascript in Python & Django

Tags: python, django, encoding, character-encoding

On a website I have the word `pluș` sent via POST to a Django view.
It is sent as `plu%25C8%2599`. So I took that string and tried to figure out a way how to make `%25C8%2599` back into `ș`.

I tried decoding the string like this:

```
from urllib import unquote_plus
s = "plu%25C8%2599"
print unquote_plus(unquote_plus(s).decode('utf-8'))
```

The result i get is `pluÈ` which actually has a length of 5, not 4.

How can I get the original string `pluș` after it's encoded ?

edit:

I managed to do it like this

```
def js_unquote(quoted):
  quoted = quoted.encode('utf-8')
  quoted = unquote_plus(unquote_plus(quoted)).decode('utf-8')
  return quoted
```

It looks weird but works the way I needed it.

Comment: Which unicode character is that supposed to be? U+0219 (Latin small s with comma below) or U+015F (latin small S with cedilla)?

Comment: @bgporter: S-comma, U+0219. It's irrelevant which letter though, as I'm having this problem for other unicode letters as ț, â, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL-decode twice, *then* decode as UTF-8.

Comment: If I URL-decode twice then decode as UTF-8 I get `'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 3-4: ordinal not in range(128)` :(

Comment: @yoshi: That's your console being unable to output it. The result is fine.

Comment: `print unquote_plus(unquote_plus('plu%25C8%2599')).decode('utf-8')` gives me `pluș`. But when I put it inside the application it spews that ascii error :| It's on the same machine, same environment.

Comment: Is the decoded result being saved to a database? If so, I'm guessing  it might be the database not configured with utf-8 as the encoding.

Comment: The result is saved in a MySQL database but it has utf8 encoding. The problem occurs before querying the database.

Comment: What component of the client encodes pluș as plu%25C8%2599 when your form action=POST? Is there some other measure being taken client-side to encode the input as such?

Answer (score 1):

You can't unless you know what the encoding is. Unicode itself is not an encoding. You might try BeautifulSoup or UnicodeDammit, which might help you get the result you were hoping for.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

I hope this helps!

Also take a look at:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: I should note that Ignacio's answer is the solution for you specific problem, but keep in mind that you won't always know the encoding of what your user is posting.

Comment: Also, please excuse my suggestion if you were already familiar those links and how Unicode and encoding works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
unquote_plus(s).encode('your_lang_encoding')
```

I was try like that. I was tried to sent a json POST request by HTML form to directly a django URI, which is included unicode characters like `"şğüöçı+"` and it works. I have used `iso_8859-9` encoder in `encode()` function.